# Disabling Mousewheel JS horizontal scroll under certain screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I'm using .mousewheel to translate my downwards scroll into horizontal scroll on desktop, however for mobile I want to disable this behavior. I have tried the following:

```
if ( $(window).width() > 480) {     
    $('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * -0.5);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
else {
    $("html, body, *").bind("mousewheel", function() {
        return false;
    });
}
```

But no success, the horizontal scrolling works fine but the body content is still locked in place on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the viewport width:

```
var viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)
```

Then you can just make a small change to your `if` statement:

```
if (viewportWidth > 480) { ... }
```

### Full code example

This includes a little "fix-up" with the way that the scroll translation was happening - I couldn't get the previous way to work.

```
var viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

if (viewportWidth > 480) {
    $('body').mousewheel(function(e) {
        $(this).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft() - e.deltaY);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
} else {
    $("body").on("mousewheel", function() { return false; });
}
```

Comment: Tried this and my normal scrolling still doesnt work, is there anything I'm missing?  

 `var viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0)

if (viewportWidth > 480) { 
 $('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * -0.5);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
else {
   $("html, body, *").bind("mousewheel", function() {
        return false;
    });
}`

Comment: Awesome, it works on mobile now (as far as I know) which is just what I needed. The only issue is it wont work on a scaled desktop browser window but thats not a problem since this is a personal website. Thank you.